# Jquery, как получить значение атрибута после его изминения?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Условно есть код 2 кнопки с атрибутами, которые подставляются к атрибуту третьей кнопки, после третья кнопка, которая должна вывести этот атрибут. Но выдает empty sting.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".paskal").click(function(event) {
    video = $(this).data('video');
    $('.play').attr('data-play', video);
  });

  $('.play').click(function(e) {
    atplay = $(this).data('play');
    console.log(atplay);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="paskal" data-video="bNwEHzce54Q">111</p>
<p class="paskal" data-video="br87WXibQE8">222</p>
<button class="play" data-play="">click</button>
```

Comment: зачем вы устанавливаете атрибут через `attr`? `data('play', video)` все успешно работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let video;
    let atplay;

    $(".paskal").click(function(e) {
      video = $(this).attr('data-video')
      $('.play').attr('data-play', video);
      //если нужно прямо написать ссылку в кнопке - то вот
      $('.play').html(video);
    });

    $('.play').click(function(e) {
      atplay = $(this).attr('data-play');
      console.log(atplay);
    });
  });
```